# Load files dynamically in multiple environments

Tags: java, classloader

so I am in the process of making a small application.

Right now, the project works fine. I am running it through an IDE. The problem comes about when trying to run the project as a jar - which is the end result. Right now, it fails to properly load the required files (classes and simple ASCII files).

The method I am using is one based off of:

```
final Enumeration<URL> paths = CLASS_LOADER.getResources("");
```

Where `CLASS_LOADER` is an instance of `class.getClassLoader()`.

---

This works great when not inside a jar. Inside a jar though, it seems to fail horribly. For example, in the code above, `paths` would be empty.

I am assuming that the fault is that the files are all within a jar - the same jar to be precise.

The class path for the manifest file is blank at the moment.

---

If it helps, I have two tasks that require loading files.

1. I need to create a list of all files that are a subclass of
   another class.
2. I need to load a list of language files (all of
   which are in the same directory).

---

If you need anything else to help debug this problem or provide a solution - let me know. Thanks for reading this!

Comment: Is it a regular jar executed in a plain JVM or some kind of a container (OSGi, Spring, application server)? What is the class you get the class loader from? Do you get an application classloader?

Comment: Regular jar - plain JVM. I try to avoid 3rd party applications as much as possible. From the class where it is loaded. For example in this case, `Reflection` where I perform task 1).

Comment: I'm going to assume the application classloader would be the `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`, correct?

Comment: Yes, in a plain JVM getSystemClassLoader() returns the application CL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ClassLoader.getResources() to work you need to feed a path relative to the jar root. If you want to search the jar then ClassLoader public API won't help you. You have to use custom code based on java.util.jar.JarFile, like the one [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/SearchclassinclasspathandJarfiles.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the help! You lead me in the right direction and I can probably take it from here